# Could not use ngx-bootstrap-modal with angular universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

When I try to use ngx-bootstrap modal with angular universal I am getting this error

[image]

Has anyone fixed or came across this error ?

I am currently using angular version 6.1.3

Answer (score 0):

use 3.1.1 version of ngx-bootstrap please